# What is the difference between createElementNS with a prefix and without it?

Tags: javascript, dom, xhtml, xml-namespaces

In a JS linked to an XHTML page, I create new elements using `createElementNS`, like this:

```js
const NS = 'http://my.site/xmlns';
const el1 = document.createElementNS(NS, 'custom');
const el2 = document.createElementNS(NS, 'p:custom');
```

I cannot understand what is the difference between the element created with namespace prefix in second argument and the one created without it. For instance, these CSS rules have identical effect on *both* elements:

```css
@namespace p url('http://my.site/xmlns');
p|custom { background: yellow; }
```

Next, call of `document.getElementsByTagNameNS(NS, 'custom')` returns a `HtmlCollection` with *both* elements, whereas `document.getElementsByTagNameNS(NS, 'p:custom')` returns an empty `HtmlCollection`, what seems strange to me.

So what is the difference between creating elements with a namespace prefix and without it?

Answer (score 0):

[`document.createElementNS()`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-createelementns) expects the second parameter to be a qualified tag name. `p:custom` is a qualified tag name, so `document.createElementNS(NS, 'p:custom')` is more correct; I suspect the reason `document.createElementNS(NS, 'custom')` works is due to legacy reasons.

[`document.getElementsByTagNameNS()`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbytagnamens) on the other hand expects the second parameter to be a local tag name. `custom` is a local tag name. (If `custom` does not have a namespace, then it is also its qualified name.)

Since your elements are namespaced, and their qualified name is `p:custom`, their local name is `custom`, and so `document.getElementsByTagNameNS(NS, 'p:custom')` returns nothing because `p:custom` is not their local name.

Comment: A qualified name (QName) doesn't necessarily have to be qualified with a namespace prefix for `createElementNS()` to work if the namespace specified in the first argument has been declared with a namespace prefix earlier in the document. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS

Comment: @Scott Marcus: Ah, but how come? Neither the spec nor MDN appears to state this explicitly, so there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you, but the MDN page does show it being used without an expressed QName, but with that same Namespace having already been declared (with a prefix) in the document, so it appears that if you are specifying a Namespace that has already been declared with a prefix, that the new element that you do specify, will implicitly have the correct QName.

Comment: This link: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#NT-QName does appear to indicate that a QName is valid with or without a prefix. I found that page by following #2 (QName production) from this link: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#validate

Comment: @Scott Marcus: I think I get it now. The DOM spec [says](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element-qualified-name) "An element’s qualified name is its local name if its namespace prefix is null, and its namespace prefix, followed by ':', followed by its local name, otherwise." so if I understand it right, the namespace prefix may be omitted, but the element belongs to the namespace anyhow.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I interpret it as well. I also see this *"Definition: A qualified name is a name subject to namespace interpretation."* on this page:  https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#dt-qualname, which (if you think about it) means that a new element created in some explicit namespace that has already been declared with a prefix would be subject to "namespace interpretation".

Comment: @Scott Marcus: Thanks for the additional insight.

Comment: But I’m still a bit confused that in JS there is no way to bind a namespace to its prefix, i.e. to define that `p` is a prefix for `http://my.site/xmlns` namespace. It is possible in XHTML with `xmlns` attribute, and in CSS with `@namespace` rule, but not in JS. So I think specifying namespace prefixes in JS code has no sense (like in `el2` from my example), because the script cannot resolve them anyway. Have I missed something?